# Lektor command-line installation fails on OS X 10.11.6

Tags: macos, installation, lektor

I've just installed Lektor desktop app for OS X on two computers, and when I select "Install Shell Command", it prompts for admin credentials (my default user account is not admin in either case) and after I've entered the admin details it then responds with:

> Error
>   Failed to install shell commands

A search for 'lektor' in the console revealed no log entries.

Both machines have XCode 8.0 installed (don't know if this makes a difference).

(FYI, but not part of this question, subsequent attempts to install the Command Line App via the bash script succeeded on one and failed on the other computer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

didn't work for me either. So I looked at the shell script for command line installation and saw that it is basically only a wrapper around a python script.

Solution:

I copy/pasted the python code from the shell script into a file and then ran it on the command line. Installation worked fine then.

Steps I've taken:

1. Environment: macOS 10.12.1 with python 2.7.12_2 installed via homebrew, fish shell (just a bash replacement)
2. used the "curl ..." link from getlektor.com to download the script -
   you need to modify it to get the file without
   immediately installing: 
   `curl -sf https://www.getlektor.com/install.sh > getlektor.txt`
3. open `getlektor.txt` in an editor and copy the python code into a new which named "install_lektor.py". The python code starts with the line
   "`import os`" and ends with the line "`main()`"
4. run the new python script with "`python install_lektor.py`"

Hope this helps!